# Cannot Use Whole Disk after Disk Upgrade

Tags: command-line, partitioning, kernel, disk, vps

I upgraded the disk size of my VPS from 20GB to 40GB. I cannot use this newly added 20GB. `fdisk -l` shows 40GB but `du -h` shows 20GB!

```
    root@ubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  656K  385M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   16G  2.5G  87% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           385M     0  385M   0% /run/user/0


root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 38.2 GiB, 40961572864 bytes, 80003072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7a5a5ba2

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 80003038 80000991 38.2G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Conflict: `/dev/sda1  *     2048 80003038 80000991 38.2G 83 Linux` VS. `/dev/sda1        19G   16G  2.5G  87% /`

Comment: The command you are looking for is probably `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`. But first study its `man` page.

Comment: Right, I've posted your comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[FedonKadifeli's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359796/cannot-use-whole-disk-after-disk-upgrade/1360255#comment2329869_1359796) worked:

> The command you are looking for is probably `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Please improve this answer instead of doing just copy & paste. [Edit] the answer and explain step by step your experiences, for example.